# How to play native camera sound on Android

Tags: android, camera

I would like to play native camera shutter sound clip on camera preview capture. I'm referring to the sound clip played when `takePicture()` is called.
 How could I that? Can someone walk me through the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This resource explains how to play audio files:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

You'll probably have to provide your own shutter sound effect.

Answer (score 68):

You can use the [`MediaActionSound`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaActionSound.html) class (available from API 16). For example:

```
MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
```

However, for some baffling reason, the Google developer who made this class decided blasting the sounds with 100 % volume is a good idea. Unfortunately a lot of stuff in the class is private and it is not possible to easily enhance it just by extension. That's why I created a modified version (converted to Kotlin) of this class which respects a given stream volume (e. g. media, notification etc.) or which allows setting an arbitrary volume. Please note that there is no guarantee this will not break in the future since the file paths to the system sounds are hardcoded. On the other hand the worst implication this can have is a sound will not be played. I will also create unit tests for this and if it breaks I will update the code here.

Simply call `playWithStreamVolume` for using a stream volume or call `play` with optional arbitrary volume. Do not forget to update the package.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.your.package

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.AUDIO_SERVICE
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.SoundPool
import android.util.Log
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

/**
 * Modified by Miloš Černilovský on March 16 2021: converted original class to Kotlin,
 * fixed a minor bug and added support for respecting stream volume or setting an arbitrary
 * volume. New methods added: [playWithStreamVolume], volume parameters added to [play].
 *
 * A class for producing sounds that match those produced by various actions
 * taken by the media and camera APIs.
 *
 * This class is recommended for use with the [android.hardware.camera2] API, since the
 * camera2 API does not play any sounds on its own for any capture or video recording actions.
 *
 * With the older [android.hardware.Camera] API, use this class to play an appropriate
 * camera operation sound when implementing a custom still or video recording mechanism (through the
 * Camera preview callbacks with
 * [Camera.setPreviewCallback][android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewCallback], or through GPU
 * processing with [Camera.setPreviewTexture][android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture], for
 * example), or when implementing some other camera-like function in your application.
 *
 * There is no need to play sounds when using
 * [Camera.takePicture][android.hardware.Camera.takePicture] or
 * [android.media.MediaRecorder] for still images or video, respectively,
 * as the Android framework will play the appropriate sounds when needed for
 * these calls.
 */
@Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate", "unused")
class MediaActionSound {
    private val sounds: Array<SoundState> = SOUND_FILES.indices.map {
        SoundState(it)
    }.toTypedArray()

    private val loadCompleteListener = SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener { soundPool, sampleId, status ->
        for (sound in sounds) {
            if (sound.id != sampleId) {
                continue
            }
            var playSoundId = 0
            synchronized(sound) {
                if (status != 0) {
                    sound.state = STATE_NOT_LOADED
                    sound.id = 0
                    Log.e(TAG, "OnLoadCompleteListener() error: " + status +
                            " loading sound: " + sound.name)
                    return@OnLoadCompleteListener
                }
                when (sound.state) {
                    STATE_LOADING -> sound.state = STATE_LOADED
                    STATE_LOADING_PLAY_REQUESTED -> {
                        playSoundId = sound.id
                        sound.state = STATE_LOADED
                    }
                    else -> Log.e(TAG, "OnLoadCompleteListener() called in wrong state: "
                            + sound.state + " for sound: " + sound.name)
                }
            }
            if (playSoundId != 0) {
                soundPool.play(playSoundId, sound.volumeLeft, sound.volumeRight, 0, 0, 1.0f)
            }
            break
        }
    }

    private var _soundPool: SoundPool? = SoundPool.Builder()
            .setMaxStreams(NUM_MEDIA_SOUND_STREAMS)
            .setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build())
            .build().also {
                it.setOnLoadCompleteListener(loadCompleteListener)
            }

    private val soundPool: SoundPool
        get() {
            return _soundPool ?: throw IllegalStateException("SoundPool has been released. This class mustn't be used after release() is called.")
        }

    private inner class SoundState(val name: Int) {
        var id = 0

        // 0 is an invalid sample ID.
        var state: Int = STATE_NOT_LOADED
        var volumeLeft: Float = 1f
        var volumeRight: Float = 1f
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new MediaActionSound instance. Only a single instance is
     * needed for playing any platform media action sound; you do not need a
     * separate instance for each sound type.
     */
    @Suppress("ConvertSecondaryConstructorToPrimary", "RemoveEmptySecondaryConstructorBody")
    constructor() {
    }

    private fun loadSound(sound: SoundState): Int {
        val soundFileName = SOUND_FILES[sound.name]
        for (soundDir in SOUND_DIRS) {
            val id = soundPool.load(soundDir + soundFileName, 1)
            if (id > 0) {
                sound.state = STATE_LOADING
                sound.id = id
                return id
            }
        }
        return 0
    }

    /**
     * Preload a predefined platform sound to minimize latency when the sound is
     * played later by [playWithStreamVolume].
     * @param soundName The type of sound to preload, selected from
     * SHUTTER_CLICK, FOCUS_COMPLETE, START_VIDEO_RECORDING, or
     * STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING.
     * @return True if the sound was successfully loaded.
     * @see playWithStreamVolume
     * @see SHUTTER_CLICK
     * @see FOCUS_COMPLETE
     * @see START_VIDEO_RECORDING
     * @see STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING
     */
    fun load(soundName: Int): Boolean {
        if (soundName < 0 || soundName >= sounds.size) {
            throw RuntimeException("Unknown sound requested: $soundName")
        }
        val sound = sounds[soundName]
        return synchronized(sound) {
            when (sound.state) {
                STATE_NOT_LOADED -> {
                    if (loadSound(sound) <= 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "load() error loading sound: $soundName")
                        false
                    } else {
                        true
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "load() called in wrong state: $sound for sound: $soundName")
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to retrieve [AudioManager] from the given [context] and plays the given sound with the given [streamType] volume.
     * If retrieving volume is not successful, [defaultVolume] is used. Finally calls [play].
     * @param streamType One of [AudioManager] constants beginning with "STREAM_" prefix, e. g. [AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC]
     */
    fun playWithStreamVolume(soundName: Int, context: Context, streamType: Int = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, defaultVolume: Float = 1f) {
        playWithStreamVolume(soundName, context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?, streamType, defaultVolume)
    }

    /**
     * Plays the given sound with the given [streamType] volume. If retrieving volume is not successful,
     * [defaultVolume] is used. Finally calls [play].
     * @param streamType One of [AudioManager] constants beginning with "STREAM_" prefix, e. g. [AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC]
     */
    fun playWithStreamVolume(soundName: Int, audioManager: AudioManager?, streamType: Int = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, defaultVolume: Float = 1f) {
        val volume = audioManager?.let { it.getStreamVolume(streamType) / it.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType).toFloat() } ?: defaultVolume
        play(soundName, volume, volume)
    }

    /**
     * Play one of the predefined platform sounds for media actions.
     *
     * Use this method to play a platform-specific sound for various media
     * actions. The sound playback is done asynchronously, with the same
     * behavior and content as the sounds played by
     * [Camera.takePicture][android.hardware.Camera.takePicture],
     * [MediaRecorder.start][android.media.MediaRecorder.start], and
     * [MediaRecorder.stop][android.media.MediaRecorder.stop].
     *
     * With the [camera2][android.hardware.camera2] API, this method can be used to play
     * standard camera operation sounds with the appropriate system behavior for such sounds.
     *
     * With the older [android.hardware.Camera] API, using this method makes it easy to
     * match the default device sounds when recording or capturing data through the preview
     * callbacks, or when implementing custom camera-like features in your application.
     *
     * If the sound has not been loaded by [load] before calling play,
     * play will load the sound at the cost of some additional latency before
     * sound playback begins.
     *
     * @param soundName The type of sound to play, selected from
     * [SHUTTER_CLICK], [FOCUS_COMPLETE], [START_VIDEO_RECORDING], or
     * [STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING].
     * @param leftVolume left volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
     * @param rightVolume right volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
     * @see android.hardware.Camera.takePicture
     * @see android.media.MediaRecorder
     * @see SHUTTER_CLICK
     * @see FOCUS_COMPLETE
     * @see START_VIDEO_RECORDING
     * @see STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING
     */
    @JvmOverloads // for backward Java compatibility
    fun play(soundName: Int, leftVolume: Float = 1f, rightVolume: Float = leftVolume) {
        if (soundName < 0 || soundName >= SOUND_FILES.size) {
            throw RuntimeException("Unknown sound requested: $soundName")
        }
        val sound = sounds[soundName]
        synchronized(sound) {
            when (sound.state) {
                STATE_NOT_LOADED -> {
                    if (loadSound(sound) <= 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "play() error loading sound: $soundName")
                    } else {
                        setRequestPlayStatus(sound, leftVolume, rightVolume)
                    }
                }
                STATE_LOADING -> setRequestPlayStatus(sound, leftVolume, rightVolume)
                STATE_LOADED -> soundPool.play(sound.id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 0, 0, 1.0f)
                else -> Log.e(TAG, "play() called in wrong state: " + sound.state + " for sound: " + soundName)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestPlayStatus(sound: SoundState, leftVolume: Float, rightVolume: Float) {
        with(sound) {
            state = STATE_LOADING_PLAY_REQUESTED
            volumeLeft = leftVolume
            volumeRight = rightVolume
        }
    }

    /**
     * Free up all audio resources used by this MediaActionSound instance. Do
     * not call any other methods on a MediaActionSound instance after calling
     * release().
     */
    fun release() {
        _soundPool?.let {
            for (sound in sounds) {
                synchronized(sound) {
                    sound.state = STATE_NOT_LOADED
                    sound.id = 0
                }
            }
            it.release()
            _soundPool = null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NUM_MEDIA_SOUND_STREAMS = 1
        private val SOUND_DIRS = arrayOf(
                "/product/media/audio/ui/",
                "/system/media/audio/ui/")
        private val SOUND_FILES = arrayOf(
                "camera_click.ogg",
                "camera_focus.ogg",
                "VideoRecord.ogg",
                "VideoStop.ogg"
        )
        private const val TAG = "MediaActionSound"

        /**
         * The sound used by
         * [Camera.takePicture][android.hardware.Camera.takePicture] to
         * indicate still image capture.
         * @see playWithStreamVolume
         */
        const val SHUTTER_CLICK = 0

        /**
         * A sound to indicate that focusing has completed. Because deciding
         * when this occurs is application-dependent, this sound is not used by
         * any methods in the media or camera APIs.
         * @see playWithStreamVolume
         */
        const val FOCUS_COMPLETE = 1

        /**
         * The sound used by
         * [MediaRecorder.start()][android.media.MediaRecorder.start] to
         * indicate the start of video recording.
         * @see playWithStreamVolume
         */
        const val START_VIDEO_RECORDING = 2

        /**
         * The sound used by
         * [MediaRecorder.stop()][android.media.MediaRecorder.stop] to
         * indicate the end of video recording.
         * @see playWithStreamVolume
         */
        const val STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING = 3

        /**
         * States for SoundState.
         * STATE_NOT_LOADED             : sample not loaded
         * STATE_LOADING                : sample being loaded: waiting for load completion callback
         * STATE_LOADING_PLAY_REQUESTED : sample being loaded and playback request received
         * STATE_LOADED                 : sample loaded, ready for playback
         */
        private const val STATE_NOT_LOADED = 0
        private const val STATE_LOADING = 1
        private const val STATE_LOADING_PLAY_REQUESTED = 2
        private const val STATE_LOADED = 3
    }
}
```

[I've also offered this class to Google so please upvote the issue.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182811267)

Comment: There's no volume for this method? This blasts the shutter sound at full volume, no matter what volume is set on device.

Comment: It should respect the user's current notification volume automatically.

Comment: @GreysonParrelli, well, it doesn't.

Comment: do we need to release the Soundpool after playing the audio?

Comment: @VoThanhTung I think it should be released if you are not planning to use the MediaActionSound instance again.

Comment: @Hashman it appears to use the ringer volume stream and appropriately mutes the sound if the ringer is on vibrate or silenced. This must be expected behavior for Android as this was added in conjunction with Camera2Api.

Comment: @Hashman I've added to the answer a modified version of MediaActionSound which allows for setting volume or respecting a given stream volume.

Answer (score 19):

If the system file is there, you can use it like this:

```
public void shootSound()
{
    AudioManager meng = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int volume = meng.getStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

    if (volume != 0)
    {
        if (_shootMP == null)
            _shootMP = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"));
        if (_shootMP != null)
            _shootMP.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Derzu: `_sootMP` in my case was a class member of the camera Activity. There is no need to recreate it for every capture.

Comment: In your case is great, but readers still need to know what it is.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to use SoundPool

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
int shutterSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.camera_click, 0);
```

and then to play the sound

```
soundPool.play(shutterSound, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1);
```

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html to understand the parameters.

You will need a media file called camera_click.ogg in your project at res/raw. You should be able to use the Android default sound which can be obtained from the Android open source project in the following location ( frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/camera_click.ogg ) if your project is licensed under the Apache license. If your project isn't licensed under the Apache license I have no idea if you can use it or not. I am not a lawyer.

Comment: From the docs: "priority field: the priority of the sound. Currently has no effect. Use a value of 1 for future compatibility."

Comment: Apache license is very permissive; you can use its resources in any project.

On the other hand, it is possible to look for the sound already available on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will help you to play sound only when the ringer mode is in normal mode and not in silent or vibrate.

```
private var audioManager: AudioManager? = null
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

private fun initAudio() {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "initAudio")

    audioManager ?: let {
        audioManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
    }

    mediaPlayer = try {
        MediaPlayer().apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build()
                setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
            } else {
                setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 28) {
                setDataSource(context!!, Uri.parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"))
            } else {
                setDataSource(context!!, Uri.parse("file:///system/product/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"))
            }
            prepare()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "initAudio", e)
        null
    }
}

private fun playClickSound() {

    if (audioManager?.ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        AudioManager meng = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int volume = meng.getStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        if(volume != 0)
            sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.