# Android: Play camera shutter sound programmatically

Tags: android, audio, camera

I want to play camera shutter sound programmatically. I'm not using ShutterCallback which automatically plays that sound, so I need to do it in some other way. Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2364892/1321873

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play native camera sound on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364892/how-to-play-native-camera-sound-on-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

his resource explains how to play audio files

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

You'll probably have to provide your own shutter sound effect.

If the system file is there, you can use it like this:

```
public void shootSound()
{
    AudioManager meng = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int volume = meng.getStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

    if (volume != 0)
    {
        if (_shootMP == null)
            _shootMP = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"));
        if (_shootMP != null)
            _shootMP.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

[MediaActionSound](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaActionSound.html) from API 16.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
            sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK);
        break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        break;
    }
```

Respect vibrate/silent mode in Android.

Comment: MediaActionSound is built to already respect the ringer mode if it is on vibrate or silenced so this switch case should be able to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
private fun shuttleVolume() {
    val sound = MediaActionSound()
    sound.play(MediaActionSound.SHUTTER_CLICK)
}
```

Sample code:

```
imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
    shuttleVolume()
    takePhoto()
}
```

Call it when you needed, for example before taking a photo!